# jQuery animation on changing page

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#content').load('front.php');

                $('nav a').click(function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('#content').load(page + '.php');
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

I'm using this code to load a page without refreshing the website. But what I really want is this (which works perfectly) with an animation once upon load. How shall I do this? I've tried CSS ease-in and ease-out, but since the page only loads once I've no idea.

Comment: JQuery has an animate functionality you could look at as well.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: That doesn't work? It gives me a error

Comment: Since I add for an example a .fade, it sends me to the url instead of changing page

Comment: Your question has been down voted and flagged due to it's unclear what you are asking. You have given code, but it doesn't seem to relate to what you are content is about. Your content is very broad.

Comment: @sfsefsf33fs3fs3fs You may want to review http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error going forward, it may help you get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery animate is what you are looking for, here is an example use case.

```
$( "#your_elements" ).animate({
    opacity: .75,
    left: "+=50",
    height: 1000px
});
```

This code would animate the elements selected to the states specified.

You could place this inside of a page load callback, if you wanted to have the animation fire on page load.

Jquery animate has many different capabilities which you can read more about here: [JQuery.Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

---

Lets say you want to on page load have #content "fade in".

You already have your document.load callback ready, so it would look something like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#content').load('front.php');

            $( "#content" ).animate({
                opacity: 1 // This line will animate the change in opacity 
            });            // From whatever it currently is, to 1.  

            $('nav a').click(function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                $('#content').load(page + '.php');
                return false;
            });
        });
```

You'll notice, in my comment, I said it will animate from whatever it currently is, to 1. That means if it is already 1, it won't do anything. You will probably want to set whatever you want to animate to have

opacity: 0

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do with your page, but lets say you want to make your #content fade in. I'll show you how in my answer.